# Multiple instances of a form

Tags: vb.net

Basically my server sends a client a string which is then broken down on the client side using `Dim data() As String = receivedString.Split("|"c)` an example of a string would be `MESSAGE|TestUser|This Is The Message` what i want to do when this string is received is firstly check to see if this user has already sent a message to this client before(should already have a window up with the current 'chat') if the user has sent a message before append the text to say a rich text box. if the user hasn't sent a message before a new instance of 'chat window' is created and then any future messages from the server goes to this instance of the window.

thanks,
Houlahan

```
Dim data() As String = message.Split("|"c)
    Select Case data(0)
        Case "MESSAGE"
            Try
                If conversations.ContainsKey(data(1)) Then
                    Dim convoWindow As ChatWindow
                    convoWindow = conversations.Item(data(1))
                    convoWindow.RichTextBox1.AppendText(data(2))
                Else
                    conversations.Add(data(1), New ChatWindow())
                    Dim convoWindow As ChatWindow
                    convoWindow = conversations.Item(data(1))
                    convoWindow.Show()
                    convoWindow.RichTextBox1.AppendText(data(2))
                End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this in a slew of ways.  The first that pops into my head would be to create a Dictionary object that associates your `TestUser` as the key in association with a `Form` that represents a conversation. e.g.

```
conversations.Add(testUser, new FormConversation(...))
```

When a message is received, you would reference the dictionary that kept track of all your ongoing conversations.

If no key exists with the user name, create a new form and add the user to the dictionary along with a reference to the form.  If one does exist, which can be extracted from the dictionary based on the user name, simply bring that one to the front and pass the message to it.

Comment: Ive updated my first post trying to do what you explained im not sure if im on the right tracks here but it creates the chat window but that window just freezes not entirely sure why thanks

Comment: Im not sure the code which i posted runs without any run time errors but the new instance of the form is inaccessible acts as if its crashed

Comment: @Houlahan According to your code above, your not instantiating your Form. You're simply declaring it. e.g. `Dim convoWindow As New ChatWindow()`

Comment: but am i not instantiating my form when im creating it in the dictionary? `conversations.Add(data(1), New ChatWindow())` and then simply declaring it as the item in the dictionary (the new instance of the chat window)?

Comment: i found the problem! it didn't throw an error but i could see it in the stack trace the richtextbox i was trying to append data to was throwing a cross threading error :) thanks for your help!